# SQL select - include rows that don't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help out with this SQL?

```
SELECT A.post_id, B.post_id, A.ul_value as "likes", B.ul_value as "dislikes" 
FROM wp_like_dislike_counters as A, 
wp_like_dislike_counters as B 
where 
A.post_id = B.post_id 
and A.ul_key = 'u_like' 
and B.ul_key = 'u_dislike'
```

The results I'm getting:

```
3, 3, 1, 2 
4, 4, 3, 2
```

The results I want:

```
3, 3, 1, 2 
4, 4, 3, 2 
1, 1, 0, 1
```

Below is the data in the table. Notice that the row with id of 32 has a post_id of 1 along with 1 for the l_value (meaning 1 dislike). Since this post_id has no row for "likes", I would like to display this as a 0 as in the results I want above. Is this possible with this table structure?

```
id | post_id | l_key     | l_value 
---+---------+-----------+---------
35 |       3 | u_dislike | 2 
34 |       4 | u_dislike | 2 
31 |       4 | u_like    | 3 
32 |       1 | u_dislike | 1 
36 |       3 | u_like    | 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this with conditional aggregation, not a join:

```
select post_id,
       sum(case when ul_key = 'u_like' then ul_value else 0 end) as likes,
       sum(case when ul_key = 'u_dislike' then ul_value else 0 end) as dislikes
from wp_like_dislike_counters
group by post_id;
```